# Как мне из цикла получить b?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
b = False
class MyController(Controller):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Controller.__init__(self, **kwargs)

    def  on_triangle_press(self):
       b = True 
       print(b)
       return b
    
       
    def  on_x_press (self):
        print(b)
```

как мне за пределами def  on_triangle_press(self): получить b? использую pyPS4Controller 1.2.4

Comment: Нужного вам  b вне метода не существует. Смотрите, где у вас вызывается этот обработчик и сохраняйте результат

Comment: `global`.......?

Comment: А где у вас цикл? Внутри класса можете использовать `self.b` вместо `b`, да и всё. Все методы экземпляра класса будут иметь к ней доступ.

Comment: Если придёте к решению через global, то лучше сохраняйте его в self =)

Comment: а где тут цикл?

Answer (score 2):

На уровне экземпляра класса:

```
class MyController(Controller):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Controller.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.b = False

    def  on_triangle_press(self):
       self.b = True 
       print(self.b)
       return self.b
       
    def  on_x_press (self):
        print(self.b)
```

Где у вас цикл я не понял.

Comment: я просто новичок в python (мне 12 лет поэтому за ошибки простите )терминологию плохо знаю

Comment: а как мне его (self.b) получить за пределами class?

Comment: @DimaBroLach Ну вы же создаёте как-то экземпляр класса? Ну вот допустим экземпляр класса в переменной `x`, тогда `x.b`

Comment: не понимаю объясните пожалуйста

Comment: @DimaBroLach Как вы используете `MyController`?

Comment: controller = MyController(interface="/dev/input/js0", connecting_using_ds4drv=False)

controller.listen(timeout=60)

Comment: ontroller = MyController(interface="/dev/input/js0", connecting_using_ds4drv=False)

controller.listen(timeout=60)

Comment: Ну вот в `controller.b` и будет это поле